# How to extend the class which inherits Backbone.Events?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js

I'm trying to create following structure of classes using Backbone.js inheritance model:

> Backbone.Events -> Parent -> Child

Child should call `initialize` from parent, but unfortunately it does not work. Parent methods and properties are not visible. Please help.

My code

```
var Parent = function() {
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};

_.extend(Parent.prototype, Backbone.Events, {

    initialize: function() {
        // parent init
    },
});

var Child = function() {
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};

_.extend(Child.prototype, Parent, {
    /* Inherits Parent */

    initialize: function() {
        // need to call `parent init` code
        // need to init myself (child)
        // DOES NOT WORK
        // Parent methods and properties are not visible
        Parent.prototype.initialize.call(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following approach:

```
function Parent() {
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};

_.extend(Parent.prototype, Backbone.Events, {

    initialize: function() {
        // parent init
    },
});

// pick extend method from Backbone
Parent.extend = Backbone.Model.extend;

var Child = Parent.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        // Parent methods and properties are visible
        Parent.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Artem. Could you point `Backbone.Model.extend` in backbone.js source code for my education? I can't find it.